# Retrieving related values in database from listbox PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Good day! I am fairly new in PHP and I am trying to develop a website that can retrieve and display stored information from the database. The catch is, the information that will be retrieve will be based on the selected value from the list box (the list box you can create in html).

I have one list box that contains all the names of the users and would like to display all the related information for that user on a specific table in my database.

To be completely honest, I have no idea how to do this. I can retrieve all the values from a specific table in my database and that's all I know.

Hoping someone would be patient enough to teach me how to do this or guide me if this is even possible in PHP.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But you can still guide the guy, We all had to start somewhere. Please check my answer.

Comment: You need to do some work before we can help you. We need to see the form layout, your attempt at a sql query, what the desired results are and what the actual results are.

Comment: Thank you for that, @GaijinJim. I am checking out your answer right now, thank you again.

Comment: @Len_D my plan was to actually edit this post after I've tried it myself. I was just really wondering if this is possible with PHP alone.

Comment: It is possible using PHP and Jquery/Ajax, or with PHP alone.

Comment: I see. Thank you, @Len_D for your comment. I am going to try this first and see if this could be done with PHP only by studying the links provided by GaijinJim, since I have very little knowledge about Jquery. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [read on doing database operations using PHP with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Once you've done that, the rest will be pretty easy, you will have to learn how to work with forms with PHP,
which you can do [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html).